# dynamic v-model can't show the value?

Tags: vue.js, v-model

The data

```
let design = {
   components:[
     {field:'a'},
     {field:'b'},
     {field:'c}
  ]
};

let data = {
    a:1,
    b:2,
    c:3
}
```

In the Vue

```
<div v-for((item,index) in design.components)>
  
 <input v-model="data[item.field]" />
</div>
```

when I use this written above, can't show the value.
But it's can show the value if I using below written

```
<div v-for((item,index) in design.components)>
  
 <input v-model="data[design.components[index].field]" />
</div>
```

How could this be？ anyone help,Thinks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi is your syntax correct? v-for should look like this `<li v-for="(item, index) in design.components">`

according to the documentation

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

also you have typo in your Vue `{field:'c}` it should be `{field:'c'}`

**edit:**
here is https://jsfiddle.net/v4oxzft7/

Comment: Yes,you are right.  I am too careless.

Comment: I now know that this phenomenon is caused by using the input component wrapped in a third-party library.  Thank you for pointing out my syntax mistakes